# Append or combine column wise torch tensors of different shapes

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Tensors A and B below share the row size. The 6 and 3 refers to the columns of the 2 data frame, but the B tensor has at each cell a vector of size 256.

```
A= torch.Size([17809, 6])
B= torch.Size([17809, 3, 256])
```

How do I append combine these tensors?

More detail:
A column of 'A' is a numeric vector like 'Age', In B one of the 3 columns has a set of node embeddings (vector) of size 256.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply [`torch.nn.Embedding`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Embedding.html) on `A` to embedding numeric vector then use [`torch.cat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html) to concat `embeding of A` and `B` on the `axis=1`.

*(In the below code I use random tensors)*.

```
import torch
from torch import nn

num_embeddings = 10 # fill base Age
embedding_dim = 256 # fill base of B tensor
embedding = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings, embedding_dim)

A = torch.randint(10, (17809, 6))
print(f"A   : {A.shape}")

E_A = embedding(A)
print(f"E_A : {E_A.shape}")

B = torch.rand(17809, 3, 256)
print(f"B   : {B.shape}")

C = torch.cat((E_A, B), 1)
print(f"C   : {C.shape}")
```

Output:

```
A   : torch.Size([17809, 6])
E_A : torch.Size([17809, 6, 256])
B   : torch.Size([17809, 3, 256])
C   : torch.Size([17809, 9, 256])
```

Comment: Great, I first got error _Expected tensor for argument #1 'indices' to have scalar type Long; but got torch.ShortTensor instead_. I added this to the embedding func: `x = A.clone().detach().to(torch.int64);  E_A = embedding(x)`  & works!